# How "dense" are smooth numbers?

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory

Fix an integer $d \geq 2$, and let $S = \{ p_1^{\alpha_1} p_2^{\alpha_2} \cdots p_d^{\alpha_d} \ : \ \alpha_1,\alpha_2,\dots,\alpha_d \geq 0\}$ denote the set of all $p_d$-smooth positive integers ($p_i$ denotes the $i$-th prime). I would like to ensure that each interval $[x,x+y(x))$ least  contains at least one element of $S$. How large does $y(x)$ need to be for such a statement to be true?

It's fairly clear that we need to take $y(x) \gg x/\log^d x$. Indeed, $S \cap [0,x) \sim c_d \log^d x$ for some constant $c_d$.

Heuristically, one might expect that $S \cap [0,x)$ is distributed quite uniformly in $[0,x)$ and consequently that the above bound is sharp. Is this guess close to correct? For instance, can we take $y = x/\log^{d-1} x$?

I have been able to find bounds that go in the opposite direction. For instance, Tijdeman showed in 1973 that the interval $[x,x+z)$ with $z=x/\log^c(x)$ contains at most one element of $S$, where $c$ is some explicit function of $d$ which grows quite fast (if I'm not mistaken, we can take$c = \exp(c_0 d^4)$, where $c_0$ is an absolute constant). There are also several results about the asymptotic number of smooth numbers in an interval, but the problem only appears to have been investigated when $d$ increases with $x$.

Comment: Have you figured out $d=2$? Whether you can take $y(x) = x/\log x$ basically corresponds to whether for each $x$ there exists a solution to $0 \le a\log(2)+b\log(3)-\log(x) \le \frac{1}{\log(x)}$ in non-negative integers $a,b$.

Comment: You might have a look at Theorem 4 of Hildebrand and Tenenbaum's "On Integers Free of Large Prime Factors," as well as Theorem 3 of Hildebrand's "On the Number of Positive Integers $\leq x$ and Free of Prime Factors $\leq y$." Both these results give asymptotic estimates for the number of smooth numbers in a short interval, though with slightly different notation than your's.

Comment: @mathworker21: Thanks, that's a good question! It seems that for $d = 2$, what one ultimately needs is to show that for each $Q > 1$ there is $0 < a < Q$ with $\{a \frac{\log 2}{\log 3} \} \ll 1/Q$. A similar statement, with the circle norm $|| \cdot ||$ in place of the fractional part $\{ \cdot \}$ is standard (and follows from the pigeonhole principle). Since the two statements are very close, I'm sure the other one must be true as well, but I don't have a proof.

Comment: @JoshuaStucky: Thank you!